# Pandas append function adds new columns

Tags: pandas

I want to append one row to my dataframe.
Here's the code

```
import pandas as pd
citiesDataFrame=pd.read_csv('cities.csv')
citiesDataFrame=citiesDataFrame.append({
'LatD': 50,
'"LatM"' : 70,
'"LatS"' : 40,
'"NS"': '"S"',
'"LonD"': 200,
'"LonM"':  15,
'"LonS"': 40,
'"EW"': "E",
'"City"': '"Kentucky"',
'"State"': "KY"},ignore_index=True)
citiesDataFrame
```

But when i run, append doesn't work properly. In my dataframe i have 10 columns and 128 rows, when i run the code, it appends 9 columns and 1 row ([here is modified dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QeGD.png)) to dataframe.

Comment: It shold work if column names are identical. You can check which column name differs with `idx = [df.columns[i]==list(d.values())[i] for i in range(len(d))]` and `df.columns[idx]` where `df` is your dataframe, and `d` the dictionary you wanna use to append.

Answer (score 2):

Notice it works for `LatD`. The reason is your column names aren't identical to the existing names. Seems like a quoting issue. Not sure why you have the double quotes inside the single quotes. Make the column names match and then the append will work.

Comment: actually i didn't want to change the column names so that dataframe stays as what it is. I was thinking that append should work with double quoted column names

Comment: Then decide what string you prefer and change it in both so they be identical..

Comment: You have double quoted WITHIN single quoted though. If you just had double or just had single it shouldn't matter. But you can't have one within the other or else the inner one is becoming part of the name.